# Decimal number with only 10 digits for the integer and 6 for the decimals?

Tags: php

Let's say if I have a given number 47.50 how can I allow only to have 10 digits for the integer and 6 for the decimal such like this 0000000047.500000
or given another example: 3475.95 to this 0000003475.950000

// is it okay to use str_pad? how can I use it?

```
$amount = str_pad(3475.95, 10, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: Use [sprint()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) instead

Comment: how can I achieve this with sprint also with dcimals?

Comment: `$amount = sprintf("%016.6f", 3475.95);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most elegant approach but hey, we are talking scripting, right?

```
<?php
$value = 47.56;
echo sprintf('%s.%s', 
             str_pad((int)$value, 10, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT), 
             str_pad(substr($value-(int)$value,2), 6, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT));
?>
```

---

Sorry, couldn't resist. But obviously the correct solution has been pointed out by Mark Baker in his comment above: `sprintf("%016.6f", 3475.95);`...